# Updating a page's anchor links (that have changed position)

Tags: html, css

I have a single page website I'm working on that has hidden elements that are shown / toggled upon mouse click of a link.
The problem lies in the fact that my anchor links are set from the start and when I show/expand one section of the website, the other anchor links are incorrect due to the new dimensions of the webpage.

Any workarounds / suggestions / fixes?

edit:
Say I have a smooth scroll function that latches on to an anchor link to scroll to and a nav bar:

```
//Smooth Scroll
$k(function() {
    $k('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $k(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $k('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
            if (target.length) {
                $k('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});

//Nav Bar
<nav id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about">Hello!</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" id="wedding-toggle2">Weddings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" id="events-toggle2">Events</a></li>
                        <li id="logomainli"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/puffinlogo-xsmall.png" style="vertical-align:middle !important" id="logomain"></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" id="cakes-toggle2">Cakes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" id="catering-toggle2">Catering</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

// jQuery Toggle Script:
$j('#wedding-show').click(function() {
    $j('#weddingtog').show('slow');
    $j('#weddingtog').addClass('active');
    return false;
});
$j('#wedding-hide').click(function() {
    $j('#weddingtog').hide('fast');
    return false;
});
```

So it toggles the div (show and hide) and because of that the anchor changes on the page. eg `<section id="weddings"></section>`

Comment: We need to see some html/css as there is a million ways...

Comment: Can u put ur code in codepen or jsFiddle so that anyone can see wat u doing?

Comment: Edited @LGSon (: Added in some code